# lambda's capture mechanism

Tags: c++, lambda

I have trouble understanding lambda functions and the mechanism to capture variables, so I did a little testing and arrived at really weird conclusion. that is:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
  std::function<void()> lambda;
  void DoYourStuff()
  {
    int x;
    x = 1;
    lambda = [=] () { printf("A %d\n", x);};
    lambda();
    x = 2;
    lambda(); 
  }
};

class ClassB
{
public:
  std::function<void()> lambda;
  int x;
  void DoYourStuff()
  {
    x = 1;
    lambda = [=] () { printf("B %d\n", x);};
    lambda();
    x = 2;
    lambda(); 
  }
};
```

Note: only difference is in placement of x variable;
ClassA and ClassB's functions have *different* output!

```
A 1
A 1
B 1
B 2
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this the desired behaviour?
2. if i used [&] instead of [=] in ClassA, would those lambdas be identical?
3. Is there some general rule as to when [=] actually makes copy?
4. When exactly is the capturing of variables by lambdas supposed to happen?
5. Can I force lambda to do a re-capture of variables?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what the output is? It's a bit tedious to write and run a program to test your code fragments.

Comment: Neither one compiles, so observations about what results they produce are a bit speculative.

Comment: @interjay yes int x; was misplaced,

Comment: @PeteBecker #include <stdio.h> for printf  and #include <functional> for std::function

Comment: @MikeSeymour classA prints 1 1  classB prints 1 2

Comment: @user1316208: And also fix the type of `lambda` to `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: @user1316208 - you're the one asking the question. Post code that compiles and runs and illustrates the question. Suggesting diffs from what you posted makes it less likely that someone else will do that work for you.

Comment: @PeteBecker I dont need answers from people who dont know what the code will produce, so I did not think it important to make it compilable.

Comment: @user1316208 - well, there you go. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @user1316208: Should I withdraw my answer then? I didn't know what the output would be until I fixed and ran the code, and didn't know why until I thought about it. If you want to challenge people to debug and run code in their head, then you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you proved my point, you managed to get the output by yourself and you answered my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first captures the local variable `x` by value; so it prints `1` both times, since its copy hasn't changed.

The second captures the local quasi-variable `this`, *not* the member variable `x`. So the body is equivialent to `printf("%d\n", this->x);`, and will print the new value of `2` after you change `x`.

If you were to explicitly capture `x` (i.e. `[x](){...}`), then you will see the same result as the first.

> Is this the desired behaviour?

It's the behaviour specified by the language standard.

> if i used [&] instead of [=] in ClassA, would those lambdas be identical?

No, but both would produce the same output. The first would capture the local `x` by reference, so you will see the change to it.

> Is there some general rule as to when [=] actually makes copy?

Yes, it copies the variable when the lambda is created.

> When exactly is the capturing of variables by lambdas supposed to happen?

When the lambda is created.

> Can I force lambda to do a re-capture of variables?

No. Once it's captured by value, it has its own copy of the variable, with no way to access the original. If you need to see changes to the original, then capture by reference (and take care with object lifetimes).

Comment: thx, im still interested in When exactly is the capturing of variables by lambdas supposed to happen? and Can I force lambda to do a re-capture of variables?

Comment: @user1316208: I've just added answers to your specific questions.

Comment: Is there some general rule as to when [=] actually makes copy? Obviously in classB it does not actually make an copy..  So I was interested in general rule on actually making an copy.

Comment: @user1316208: Keep in mind that a lambda is an instance of a class. When you use `[=]`, every *local* variable is passed as parameter to the constructor of that class, so the value is passed when you create the lambda. If you use `[&]` instead, they're still passed to the constructor of that class, *but* they're passed by reference instead of value.

Comment: Can I force lambda to do a re-capture of variables? When you assign lambda to variable in for-cycle as i just tested it seems to make re-capture so i was interested in making that mechanism available in other means.

Comment: @jerryCoffin It makes new instance of whole class? I thought it was just some anonymous function without name that made anonymous member variables in capture process.

Comment: @user1316208 he means that's how the lambda stores the variables; it's _as if_ it made a new class. And also, it only copies variables _that you use in the lambda_; variables that you don't use are not captured.

Comment: @user1316208: "I thought it was just some anonymous function that made anonymous member variables" That's more or less right: it's equivalent to a class, with a data or reference member to hold each captured variable, and an overload of `operator()` to make it callable. If it captures nothing, then it has no data members and is equivalent to a function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks Mike, I will accept the answer just pls explain one more thing to me:                                                                              for (int i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
      auto lambda = [=] () { printf("%d\n", i);};
      lambda();
    }                                                                            here, is there anything more happening than the re-capture of variables? Can i do my own function using assignment to re-capture lambda's variables by copy and use it safely ?

Comment: @user1316208: That's simply creating a new lambda on each iteration, capturing the current value of `i`. I don't know what your second question means, sorry.

Comment: Herb Sutter has identified this unintuitive capturing of this as the most common problem in lambda usage. He has proposed a change of semantics for C++1y. So maybe things will get better.

Comment: @MikeSeymour creating new lambda? You are implying that when variable initialized with lambda goes out of scope, that lambda is destroyed?

Comment: @user1316208: Yes. Your code contains a variable, `auto lambda`, scoped inside the for-loop body. Like any such variable, it's destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of each iteration, and a new one is created during the next iteration. If the `auto` was a typo, and you actually meant to reassign the member variable `lambda`, then that will reassign it from a newly created lambda, with newly captured values.

Comment: Past two days I have been making variables on stack, assigning lambda functions to them and passing them for later use as std::functions.  They work even after their variables go out of scope. Am I in big trouble? Is it undefindef behaviour?

Comment: I just found out lambdas can be copied - I think I understand now. thanks Mike

Comment: @user1316208: You're in big trouble if you capture a local variable *by reference* and call the lambda once it's out of scope. There's no problem if you've captured it by value; that makes a copy, which lives as long as the lambda.